# How to: output Euro symbol in pdfkit for nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, euro

Is it possible to display the Euro symbol in pdfkit for nodejs without having to embed an external font?

I am using pdfKit to generate invoices and would like to prefix my currency amounts with the Euro Symbol (€).

I've tried a number of approaches and none worked:

```
doc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .fontSize(12)
    .text('€', 10, 10); // Alt+0128 on keypad

doc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
    .fontSize(12)
    .text('\u20AC', 10, 10);
```

Comment: Could you include a bit more detail? Perhaps [a small example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out it is a font issue:

> unicode works, but you have to make sure that the font you are using
>   includes the characters you want to use. Unlike your operating system,
>   PDFKit does not do any automatic font substitution.

Source: [Reddit Thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/imjwq/pdfkit_a_powerful_pdf_generation_library_for/c254ge3) comment by [/u/devongovett](http://www.reddit.com/user/devongovett)

---

I tested two fonts that were included with pdfkit. Both 'Helvetica-Bold' and 'Times-Roman' didn't work with the unicode symbols. I noticed in the [documentation for fonts](http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#fonts) that you can add in your own fonts, so I gave the [Cardo Font](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aCardo) (hosted on Google Fonts) a go as it supports many unicode characters.

Sure enough, it worked. Here is the script I used for testing (Make sure you have the Cardo font available):

```js
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var doc = new PDFDocument();

doc.registerFont('Cardo', 'Cardo/Cardo-Regular.ttf')

doc.font('Cardo')
    .fontSize(20)
    .text('Testing [\u20AC]', 10, 10);

doc.write('out.pdf');
```

If you're set on using Helvetica-Bold, download a copy of the font elsewhere (make sure it supports the unicode characters you're after) and register it as I have with the Cardo font.

Comment: So the answer is that it is **not** possible.

Comment: Here's a list of fonts that support the Euro sign. The website also has lists for other symbols. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/fontsupport.htm