# How to render unicode symbols with PDFKit in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, pdf, unicode, fonts, pdfkit

[PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) works fine for me, but when I render symbols like ₹ and č, it doesn't show up at all (not even as character garbage).

I'm not converting a web page, I'm manually creating a PDF. Do I have to set a charset? If so, how?

And I know the fonts have the characters — I'm using the same font on the web with no problems (Open Sans).

Edit: The [PDFKit live demo](http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html) can't seem to handle these characters either.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718559/how-to-output-euro-symbol-in-pdfkit-for-nodejs)?

Comment: Yes, and I put an issue on GitHub. It appears the issue is that the font does not have the characters, and the browsers are automatically inserting them.

Answer (score 0):

Have look here
[How to output Euro symbol in pdfkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718559/how-to-output-euro-symbol-in-pdfkit-for-nodejs)

But there, make a copy of the font in your project and then use the following line of code to register the font in your pdfkit

```
doc.registerFont('Cardo', __dirname + '/../fonts/Cardo/Cardo-Regular.ttf');
```