# Python pdfkit issue in output pdf for non-English character-set

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does pdfkit support asian languages, I am from India, so my question related to languages Hindi and Marathi in python script

I am generating pdf from URL using pdfkit successfully in English language, but it is generating some junk characters in pdf if I try some other non-English languages URL, my code is

```
options = {
'page-size': 'Letter',
'margin-top': '0.75in',
'margin-right': '0.75in',
'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
'margin-left': '0.75in',
'encoding': "UTF-8",
'custom-header' : [('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')],
'cookie': [
('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
],
'no-outline': None
}
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request, response, error, parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pdfkit
config=pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
pdfkit.from_url(URL,'c:\temp\sample.pdf', configuration=config, options=options)
```

I tried with sample URL google.co.in but it is printing some junk characters.

and my target URL is https://www.loksatta.com/kolhapur-news/politics-on-the-backdrop-of-the-upcoming-elections-of-the-gokul-district-central-co-operative-banks-abn-97-2195442/

Can you pl suggest and help ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a PDF with non-ascii characters using from\_string from python-pdfkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214688/how-to-generate-a-pdf-with-non-ascii-characters-using-from-string-from-python-pd)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I do not think it gives answer and it was asked around 3 years back.

Comment: I am trying to generate PDF from given URL while question you have suggested answer for a different subject

Comment: I think that it can solve your problem if you fiddle with it a little bit.

Comment: @jpndas I tried to use "meta" tag but result is same. My code is     'encoding': "meta UTF-8"

Comment: Hi Any updates? looks like easy problem but not that easy

Comment: Please update with your comment.