# How to insert rupee currency symbol in pdf using pdfKit in nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

i am struggling to add the currency symbol to the pdf using pdfKit in node js application. i've tried with the custom font cardo but it did not help at all.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a „can I haz codes?“-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or visit [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Good luck!

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718559/how-to-output-euro-symbol-in-pdfkit-for-nodejs